# How to get reference to submit button using jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How can I get a reference to the submit button using the jQuery validation plugin?

```
function defSubmHendler(){
    $myform.validate({
        rules: rules,
        messages: messages,
        submitHandler: function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (~this form id == A){
                condition1;
            }
            else if (~this form id == B){
                condition2;
            } else {}
            ...
            $.ajax({
                ...
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In this case **this** == $.validator. I need a reference to the submit button / form in submitHandler.

Comment: How are you calling `defSubmitHandler`?

Comment: Dynamicly create form, then execute defSubmHendler('destination_form')

Answer (score 1):

Consider giving an `id` to your submit button and referencing it like so:

```
submitHandler: function() {
    //Your submit button referenced by its ID
    $("#mySubmitButton").doStuff(); 
}
```

Or, use the `form` element from your submitHandler function and find the submit button contained on that form:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
   //Via the form argument passed to the submitHandler 
   var btnSubmit = form.find(":submit");
}
```

Comment: Forms are created dynamically. Handler does not know to what form this button belongs to. My example is probably not correct. $myform is varible